# Microsoft Graph API - listitem: delta?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

It appears that there was a listitem delta endpoint in the Beta version of the Microsoft Graph API. However, it does not seem to exist in v1.0. Was support for this functionality just dropped or is there another way to achieve the same or similar functionality?

Thanks,
Rick L.